# Flutter google_maps_flutter not show location button even if myLocationButtonEnabled is set to true

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart

i am new in flutter and i'm build a simple app with google_map_flutter package.

I understand that the first time the location button is not showed due to location permission. I would like to update the state of the location button to true once the user grant the permission. below the code.

```
 children: [
      GoogleMap(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: _bottomPaddingOfMap, top: 32),
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        myLocationButtonEnabled: _myLocationButtonEnabled,
        initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
        myLocationEnabled: true,
        zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
        zoomControlsEnabled: true,
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _controllerGoogleMap.complete(controller);
          newGoogleMapController = controller;

          setState(() {
           //..... update _myLocationButtonEnabled??
            _bottomPaddingOfMap = 280.0;
          });
          locatePosition();
        },
      ),....
```

I'm using a permission_handler package but not sure about how to use it. I guess I've to update the `_myLocationButtonEnabled` variable to true once user granted permission.

How can I do this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Where are you trying to run the app? in Android? or iOS?

Comment: I'm running the app in Android